# How to create a GUI for turtlebot

Tags: ros, turtlebot, ros-kinetic, rosbridge, gui

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am new to ROS and currently I can run a launch file which tell the turtlebot where to go but he next step is to create a GUI with different button so it will run different launch file when the button is pressed. After some research I think ROSbridge is what I need but I am very confused on how it works. If you have any idea, please help. Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280943/how-to-create-a-gui-for-turtlebot/) by [Ashecotton](https://answers.ros.org/users/33434/ashecotton/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-01-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could look at making a Python [rqt plugin](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20Python%20Plugin).

If you want a standalone GUI with none of rqt's extra features, here's a really good video series to get you started in 10 minutes:
[Designing a GUI](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CNgfM2UAReA)

Unfortunately it doesn't cover ROS integration.

Either way, I don't think ROSbridge is required unless you want a web interface.

---

Originally posted by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) with karma: 2331 on 2018-01-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ashecotton](https://answers.ros.org/users/33434/ashecotton/) on 2018-01-27**:
Thank you so much!!!!

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2018-01-29**:
Alternatively: [A webpage](http://robotwebtools.org/)